# Coloring of Regions Formed by a Loop in the Plane

Tags: graph-theory, curves, coloring

### The Claim

Suppose $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a $C^1$ curve in the plane such that

1. $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$
2. $\gamma'(t) > 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$
3. $\gamma^{-1}(p)$ contains at most $2$ elements for all $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Then $\gamma$ divides the plane into regions that can be colored with $2$ colors in such a way that adjacent regions do not have the same color.

### Attempts at a Proof

This is presented as an elementary exercise in a textbook, but it's not obvious to me at all.

I tried to recast this as a graph theory problem, with the regions acting as vertices which are connected by an edge only if the regions are adjacent. After looking at a few examples, a proof didn't suggest itself to me.

I then tried to really use hypotheses 2 and 3 on $\gamma$. To me, what these hypotheses imply is that whenever $\gamma$ intersects itself, it does so by crossing itself. Moreover, when it crosses itself, it does so in such a way that the region it enters into is split into a well-defined left (in the direction of motion) part and right part. My idea was then to just color the left part one color and the right part the other color. However, this coloring doesn't actually work out. You'll sometimes color one region both colors according to this rule.

I tried variations on the previous idea but didn't get anywhere, at which point I decided to make this post.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is easy (it is not easier than the Jordan Curve Theorem). However, there is the following "standard" idea: pick a region in the complement of your curve, and draw a  ray to infinity.  This will intersect the curve in some number of points. The key observation is that the parity of the number of intersections only depends on the region and **not** on the point, nor on the direction of the line. If the line is tangent to the curve somewhere that counts as two intersections, and if the line goes through a double point, that also counts as two intersections. To make this into a complete argument, I strongly suggest reading:

*Milnor, John W.*, Topology from the differentiable viewpoint, Charlottesville: The University Press of Virginia. IX, 64 p. (1965). [ZBL0136.20402](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0136.20402).

Comment: I thought about the Jordan curve theorem when I first saw this problem and got nervous. Let's bracket the details and rigor as much as possible. I assume that was the author's intent since this was an exercise in Chapter 1 of an intro to knot theory book. Is there an "intuitive" explanation of this fact? That is, is there a proof which may be difficult to formalize, but nevertheless makes it clear that the claim should be true? Or is the idea you give the best thing you're aware of in that direction?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Yes, what I describe is probably the most intuitive explanation, and to convince yourself why this is true, keep your point fixed, and rotate the ray around. You can fairly easily convince yourself that the parity is constant.

Comment: I guess it is pretty intuitive to make a parity argument when you're trying to 2-color something. I also think I see the idea behind it. The argument makes me wonder. Could we weaken the hypotheses substantially? It seems all we need is that $\gamma$ is continuous and that its fibers have size at most $2$. Or is there some counterexample I'm not thinking of?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Yes, you are right, but for smooth curves you can weasel out with polygonal approximation, but with just continuous curves it is a bit more involved.